# CKEditor 5 Image Plugin Got Error on React

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, craco

I am using craco in a React app. I want to integrate CKEditor 5 as the content editor. Without the plugin, my app has no issues. However, when I install and use the image plugin, I encounter an error like this:

`./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/theme/placeholder.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/theme/placeholder.css) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'parent') at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.